# Are std::async calls cheap?

Tags: c++

I've been reading about std::async and if I understand correctly, it spanws a thread everytime you call it. I think threads are costly to make, because it's a system call which triggers the process to make a fork of itself and possibly copy some structures. I don't think operating systems were designed with the intent of spawning 100 threads in a second, for example.

Am I rigth? Should I avoid the usage of asyncs?

My idea was to, instead of creating a task executor that retrieves tasks (std::function's) from a FIFO in a while(true) loop, simply create std::async's with the tasks and let them execute and since I don't care about the output, don't even store them in a future.

Comment: If you [read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) the details of std::async, no where does it mention every call launches a new thread. It may offload to a threadpool or do whatever it wants.

Comment: It's entirely up to the implementation of your standard library, a good implementation should use a thread pool so will only create a new thread the first time you call std::async

Comment: It's specified that thread locals are initialized for each `std::async` call where `std::launch::async` is specified, so that pretty much means a new thread for each call.  Indeed, that's what [libstdc++ does](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/future#L1668).

Comment: _I don't think operating systems were designed with the intent of spawning 100 threads in a second._ Modern systems can create much much more than 100 threads per second. Even on my Surface Pro inside Linux virtual machine, the observed number is around **33 thousand** created threads/s.

Comment: @MilesBudnek That hardly implies a new thread. Runtime could as well hook the "`StartWork()`" call and run all the constructors for thread locals.

Comment: Task executor is preferred over a bunch of async calls. Though, in my case, I manage to use a limited number of threads and they simply communicate with each other. So I don't even have an executor.